# Ускорение алгоритма скрипта python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Подскажите как можно ускорить выполнение скрипта на `python`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests
import calendar 
import time

def parse(link):
    response = requests.get(link)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        all_station = soup.find("ul", {"class":"big-blue-billet__list"})
        all_link_station = [[link['href'],link.getText()] for link in all_station.select("a")]

    return all_link_station 


def main(params):
    station_static = {}
    for link in parse('http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/archive.php?id=by'):
        response = requests.get(f'http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/{link[0]}',params=params)
        statics_dict = {}
        if response.status_code == 200:
            soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
            date_time = ['-'.join(dt.getText().split()) for dt in soup.select(".archive-table-left-column table tr" )[1:]]
            temperature = [t.find_all('td')[5].getText() for t  in soup.select(".archive-table-wrap  table tr")[1:]]
            for el in range(len(date_time)):
                statics_dict[date_time[el]]=temperature[el]
        station_static[link[1]] = statics_dict

    return station_static

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    params = {
        'bday':1, #первый день месяца
        'fday':28, #последний день
        'amonth':2, #номер месяца январь-1 декабрь-12
        'ayear':2011, #год
        'bot':2, #защита от ботов
    }
    main(params)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

сейчас время выполнения 46 секунд. Думаю как-то можно распараллелить функцию `main` , конкретно цикл

```
for link in parse('http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/archive.php?id=by'):
```

и в разных потоках получить данные с разных ссылок. Но мало в этом опыта и не знаю в какую сторону смотреть. Подскажите как поступать в таких случаях.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В нынешней реализации библиотека multiprocessing позволяет весьма просто и удобно распараллеливать вычисления:

```
# Добавим в импорт
import multiprocessing as mp

# сделаем функцию из тела цикла    
def fun1(args):
    link, params = args
    response = requests.get(f'http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/{link[0]}', params=params)
    statics_dict = {}
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        date_time = ['-'.join(dt.getText().split()) for dt in soup.select(".archive-table-left-column table tr")[1:]]
        temperature = [t.find_all('td')[5].getText() for t in soup.select(".archive-table-wrap  table tr")[1:]]
        for el in range(len(date_time)):
            statics_dict[date_time[el]] = temperature[el]
    #station_static[link[1]] = statics_dict
    return (link[1], statics_dict)


def main(params):
    station_static = {}
    # создаем пул 
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    # собираем список аргументов функции
    links = parse('http://www.pogodaiklimat.ru/archive.php?id=by')
    # вперед
    lst = pool.map(fun1, zip(links, [params]*len(links)))
    return lst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    params = {
        'bday':1, #первый день месяца
        'fday':28, #последний день
        'amonth':2, #номер месяца январь-1 декабрь-12
        'ayear':2011, #год
        'bot':2, #защита от ботов
    }
    print(dict(main(params)))
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Примерно в 7-8 раз быстрее

Comment: круто, ускоряет в 13 раз у меня. Я пробовал `multiprocessing` но не совсем понял как туда передать `params`. Спасибо!

Comment: а пул в конце закрывать не надо? или он закрывается автоматически?

Comment: И здорово. На этой задаче ускорение замазывается скоростью доступа в инет. На вычислениях примерно пропорционально числу ядер

Comment: я не закрываю, но если прога продолжит работать, возможно, и надо. Почитайте :) я тоже прсмотрю

Comment: Похоже, что  pool.close() нужен только, чтоб срубить в аварийных ситуациях

Comment: В любом случае лучше использовать менеджер контекста, т.е. `with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool: ...` и пусть он автоматом закрывается по окончании блока. Но кажется тогда надо проитерироваться по результату `pool` прежде чем его возвращать. Ну там `list` от него взять например. Если ничего не путаю.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, очень разумный комментарий. Нет, ничего не надо, просто `with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool: lst = pool.map(fun1, zip(links, [params]*len(params)))`  там все равно дальше словарь делается :)

Comment: можно еще вопрос? только сейчас заметил что он не обходит все ссылки, а берет только первых 5. В чем проблема?

Comment: Я описался =, должно быть `[params]*len(links)`, а не `[params]*len(params)` поправил