# Python - многопоточность и асинхронность

Tags: python, многопоточность, асинхронность

Делаю парсер на `python` смысл такой -

- скрипту дают 10 ссылок (например)
- дальше что бы не ждать долго пока он проверит все ссылки надо запустить этот скрипт в многопоточности
- скрипт запускается несколько раз и проверяет одновременно ссылки

как это организовать?
или как сделать что бы он проверял ссылки быстрее - запросы отправляются на сайт с помощью библиотеки `requests`

пробовал написать что-то из статей которые читал но в итоге всё равно он синхронно читает ссылки по порядку

```py
prx = {"https" : "0.0.0.0:9999"}

r = httpx.get(url , proxies=prx)
if r.status_code == 404:
    print("page is not defined")
    return
if r.status_code == 403:
    print("proxy 403 - замена прокси")
    prx = getProxy()
    return
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')
#ниже самой парсинг даных


#когда использовал requests то всё проходило через прокси без ошибки 403 , как изменил на grequests или httpx то всегда получаеться ошибка 403 что значит что прокси не подключилось и запрос исходит с моего ip
```

Comment: Ну на сколько я знаю, питон вроде как всегда работает в 1 потоке. Если надо настоящую асинхронность, то лучше тогда GO использовать...

Comment: @АлексейБелкин *Настоящую параллельность. А асинхронно либо псевдопараллельно питон работает прекрасно. Да и параллельно работает, если несколько процессов запустить. Только для таких задач это ни к чему.

Comment: Сам по себе requests не позволяет запросы асинхронно выполнять - он блокирует поток при запросе (нужно запросы в отдельные потоки/процессы выносить, чтобы они могли параллельно выполняться). Если нужна асинхронность, используйте [aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp) или [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx) вместо requests. Можно также использовать [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests), он позволяет несколько запросов одновременно/асинхронно выполнять, при этом без async/await синтаксиса, но код все равно  придется немного переработать.

Comment: Для httpx естественно [асинхронный](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) вариант кода нужно писать (в readme на гитхабе показан синхронный вариант, он в работе не будет особо отличаться от requests).

Comment: @insolor - а как с  `grequests` использовать proxy ?

Comment: @Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA - обновил

Comment: Сфокусируйте вопрос на одной проблеме. Или многопоточность не работает (и тогда нужен код с многопоточностью, который у вас не работает) или проблема с прокси (тогда нужно убрать все не относящееся к прокси). `0.0.0.0` - это локалхост. И конфигурацию прокси вы указываете не так, как в доке https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#http-proxying

Comment: @IgorBiyar про прокси вам уже написали, ну и это синхронный вариант кода, так параллельная обработка не получится.

Comment: @IgorBiyar в grequests - по идее так же как в requests, он как обертка над requests работает.

Comment: Вот это может что подскажет - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272976/Ускорение-алгоритма-скрипта-python/1272988#1272988